# List view with icon

Tags: java, android

How can I add icons next to the listview text without using another class

```
int icons_lv = (R.drawable.icon_1, R.drawable.icon_3,
    R.drawable.icon_3, );

listView = findViewById(R.id.list_view_app_ifo);
    String [] values = new String[] {
            "Check for an update" ,
            "ٌRate App",
            "Tell us about your feedback" };

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            if (position ==0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + getPackageName()));
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            if (position ==1) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + getPackageName()));
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this from Custom Adapter only.
Here is the code for this.

```
class CustomAdapter(var context: Context, list: ArrayList<UserObj>?) :
BaseAdapter(), Filterable {
var inflter: LayoutInflater
var originalList: ArrayList<UserObj>? = ArrayList(list)
override fun getCount(): Int {
    return list!!.size
}

override fun getItem(i: Int): UserObj? {
    return list[i]
}

override fun getItemId(i: Int): Long {
    return i.toLong()
}

override fun getView(i: Int, view: View?, viewGroup: ViewGroup): View {

    var view: View? = view
    view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.spinner_item, null)
    val name = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.textView) as TextView
    val image = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.imageView) as ImageView
    val userData = list[i]
    name.text = userData.name
    Glide.with(context)
            .load(userData.imageUrl)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.spinner_dot)
            .error(R.drawable.spinner_dot)
            .into(image)
    return view
}
```

Here **spinner_item** is the layout to load with each list row.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom list adapter for your problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).